# Ionic Framework Popup view issue on Android

Tags: ionic-framework

I have added popupover's to any app on Ionic framework and it looks perfect in IOS but the popupovers are looking totally different and out of place on Android.

Any ideas why?

Here's a picture with screenshots taken from an Iphone and on the right an android phone.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably caused by the transitioning between the views. It is working differently according to the platform. This is usually causing differences between the Android view and the iOS view.

You can read more here  - http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider